# What kind of random numbers source does getnewaddress in Bitcoin Core API (bitcoind) uses?

Tags: bitcoind, api, address-generation, random

Is it an internal PRNG? Is it fed  from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`? How secure is it? If I have a hardware (TRNG) plugged in feeding my `/dev/random` will this source of entropy get used by `bitcoind`?

Comment: Well OpenSSL handles most cryptography things in Bitcoin.

Comment: In this particular case, it's the RAND_bytes call from OpenSSL.

Comment: @DiegoBasch: May I suggest you upgrade your comment to an answer, ideally with a link to the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others mentioned Bitcoin core uses [OpenSSL random sources](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Sources).

This means that it uses any random source available, like:

- the operation system, i.e. interrupts
- random sources of the CPU or the chip set
- dedicated hardware for entropy generation

So in order to make sure your hardware random generator works with Bitcoin you must make sure it works with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

[It uses RAND_bytes from OpenSSL](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/2aed2b30b112aaaf7d46df4fd947648ca8df4e67/src/key.cpp#L363). The relevant call is `CKey::MakeNewKey`.

`getnewaddress` is in rpcwallet.cpp. It tries to get a key from the pool, and if the pool is empty it allocates a new one which is populated using RAND_bytes.